# The non-abstract class '_FakeScrollContext' is missing implementations for these members + flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, version-control, flutter-dependencies

I just migrated my flutter project to null safety, and upgraded the dependencies in my pubspec.yaml too.
There is no issues or errors.
But when i try to run my flutter project, im getting the below error

```
Error: The non-abstract class '_FakeScrollContext' is missing implementations for these members:
../…/lib/scrolls_to_top.dart:112
 - ScrollContext.devicePixelRatio
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.
class _FakeScrollContext extends ScrollContext {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Context: 'ScrollContext.devicePixelRatio' is defined here.
../…/widgets/scroll_context.dart:47
  double get devicePixelRatio;
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

But i resolved the solution for temporarily by fixing in that local file where it navigated the error from the above error.
As a developer, i cant ask my team members everyone to change in there local folder. So changing the local file won't work for me.
Is there any alternate solution for the above issue to be fixed.

Comment: How do I stop the scroll Behaviour with the scrollController object?